# In CMake, how can I use the same precompiled headers on multiple targets without introducing a dependency?

Tags: cmake, precompiled-headers

I have several targets that want to use the same set of precompiled headers.  In theory this should be easy, according to the docs:

```
target_precompile_headers(target1 PUBLIC header1.h header2.h header3.h header4.h)
target_precompile_headers(target2 REUSE_FROM t1)
```

The problem is this introduces target1 as a dependency on target2. This will rebuild target1 every time the precompiled headers need to be rebuilt when I am trying to build target2.

I attempted feeding the list of headers as a newline-delimited string, i.e. something like this:

```
list(APPEND PRECOMPILED_HEADERS_L header1.h header2.h header3.h header4.h)
string(REPLACE ";" "\n" PRECOMPILED_HEADERS "${PRECOMPILED_HEADERS_L}")
target_precompile_headers(target1 PUBLIC ${PRECOMPILED_HEADERS})
target_precompile_headers(target2 PUBLIC ${PRECOMPILED_HEADERS})
```

What ends up happening is you have a single #include in the generated cmake_pch.hxx which copies the newlines and all into that single include.  Of course I could just change `"\n"` to `"\n#include"` which does appear to work, but that is likely to break in the future.

How do I properly reuse the same set of headers in multiple targets without introducing a dependency?

Comment: What is the problem with the dependency? Of course it should be recompiled if the dependency has been changed, how else you suppose the reusing would work? Reusing an existing PCH will always introduce a dependency because it is a dependency.

Comment: And if you need just to reuse the list of the headers then just reuse it. Remove this `string(replace...)` line.

Comment: @ixSci Because there are several scenarios where you only care about the pch and not the actual dependency.  As an example, a test runner that does fresh checkouts shouldn't have to rebuild the main project when all it cares about is the pch.  Or if the pch is being used in a unit test project, you only want to see how a change to code effected the unit tests, and the code change wasn't made in a file included in the precompiled headers.

Comment: @ixSci About the replace, maybe I wasn't clear enough, but `target_precompiled_headers`  if fed an argument via ${} or $<> treats it as a single header.  So you would get one single #include statement with the entire list.  Which is why the 'hack' I mentioned is necessary.

Comment: You can create a dependency which will have PCH only and nothing else. Reuse that dependency everywhere you need this particular PCH. Regarding one file: that's how PCH works, you have one file included everywhere, I'm not sure what you want multiple headers for. But it is certainly not how PCH are meant to be used.

Comment: @ixSci If your string is "<vector>\n<unordered_map>" you get #include <vector>\n<unordered_map>.  Not #include <vector> \n #include<unordered_map>.  That is what I mean by treating a string or list as a single file.

Comment: That's not how it should be. If you did everything according to the docs and it still generates an incorrect cmake_pch.h then file a bug report. It is supposed to work correctly w/o any interference. All these substitutions should not be needed at all.